# Center-Align "Title" of Picture Library Slideshow Web Part

Tags: web-part

I'm new to SharePoint 2013 and have no experience with web design / script editing. Please assist with figuring out how to center the "Title" of an image to the middle the picture. Right now, the "Title" is Left aligned.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the css rule to the page you are displaying the Picture Slide show:

You can either add a script editor web part on the page and add the following css:

```
<style>
    div[ID^="MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart"] {text-align:center;}
</style>
```

[image]

Or

add it directly to your custom css
You can see in the screen shot above, the title of the photo is centered!

Comment: Thank you so much Ahmed, I can't believe how much of an advantage it is to learn how to write the code...the out of the box web has limitations...